# javascript changes doesn't show on browser

Tags: javascript

Html and CSS was a breeze but Javascript has been difficult to grasp.. For the past week and a half I've been trying different learning styles..

My main issue now Javascript isn't found when I inspect the page.

Any light shed or tips given would be greatly appreciated.

[I think the order of my files are incorrect but unsure how to correct it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqddY.png)

Comment: There is a path issue.  Use ``../main.js`` instead of ``scripts/main.js``.  Try to keep files in a proper structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but it looks like the path is wrong.

Looking at your folder structure, the `main.js` seems to be one folder before your `index.html`. So we have 2 solutions:

1. Change the `src` attribute to `../main.js`.
2. Create a folder called `scripts` inside the `beginner-html-site...` and move the `main.js` file inside it. This way your current `<script>` tag should work.

Comment: Thank you so much .. Did exactly that

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put ../ before the file name in your src reference to ensure it goes up a level to actually access your script file. This is due to your index.html file being in a sub-folder of the main directory.
for example
src="../main.js"
remove the scripts as scripts is the name of the root folder and by navigating up a level using .. you wont need to reference the root folder

Comment: sorry i omitted a . accidentally

Comment: It would probably be better in this case to move `main.js` into a scripts directory in your beginner-html-site.. folder (so, `beginnter-site-html-styled-gh-pages/scripts/main.js`).That would make the path in the HTML correct and create a proper directory structure as well.

Comment: Thank you so much .. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load the script from the wrong location in index.html line 24.

You are using a relative URL (points to a file within your website). But the path doesn't match where your script is. Solution:

1. Make a folder called `scripts` inside your beginner-html-site-styled-gh-pages folder. Place the main.js file inside.
2. In case you would like to keep your main.js file where it is, then update the src attribute to be `../main.js`.

`../` goes one directory up.

Comment: Thank you so much .. Wont be making the same mistake again

Answer (score 0):

The `script` tag on line 24 is trying to import a file called `main.js` under the`scripts` folder that exists on the same level as your `index.html` which it doesn't find.

You need either to create a folder called `scripts` on the same level as `index.html` and cut/paste your `main.js` file or correct the path to your js file:

```
<script src='../main.js'></script>
```

Read this [post](http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weeknine/including-javascript.html) to learn more about how to include JavaScript files in your page

Comment: Thank you so much .. Much appreciated